# Вывод минимума и максимума из массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Задача поставлена следующим образом:

1. Объявление необходимых переменных
2. Ввод размера массива
3. Заполнение массива с помощью rand()
4. Вывод всего массива
5. Вывод по вводу числа:

   1. Минимальное значение в массиве
   2. Максимальное значение в массиве
   3. Сумма всех чисел в массиве

Застрял я на выводе минимума/максимума.
Сложность состоит в том, что числа в массиве могут повторяться, числа 1 вообще может и не быть, и так далее.
Как это реализовать правильно?

Вот то, что имеется сейчас:

```
int main()
{
    int y, x = 0;
    cout << "Enter the massive size" << endl << "y = ";
    cin >> y;
    int * a = new int[y];
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % y;
    };
    cin >> x;
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << "," << " ";
    };
    cout << endl;
    cout << "1.Minimum\n2.Maximum\n3.Summ" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну что сложного? int min = a[0]; `for(int i = 0; i < y; ++i){if(a[i] < min)min = a[i];} для всего остального прям аналогично.

Comment: Что такое `x` и зачем оно читается из `cin`?

Comment: Что имеется в виду под "минимальное значение"? Само значение? Или его позиция в массиве?

Comment: @AnT , прошу прощения, x лишний. Именно само значение.

Comment: Что делать, если в массиве несколько одинаковых минимальных элементов - это уже у вас надо спрашивать. Если вам надо вывести только *значение* минимального элемента, то проблемы нет вообще. А если надо вывести и позицию в массиве, то все зависит от постановки задачи. Может вам надо вывести позицию первого? А может любого? А может надо вывести все позиции? "Единственно правильного" ответа не существует. Это вам виднее, мы тут не телепаты.

Comment: @Зигмунд Войцеховский Есть елгоритм std::minmax_element, который позволяет получить сразу же минимальный и максимальный элементы последовательности. Но я уверен, что ваша задача написать соответствующий код самостоятельно, не используя стандартные алгоритмы.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Минимум

```
const int *pmin = std::min_element(a, a + y);
cout << *pmin << endl;
```

Максимум

```
const int *pmax = std::max_element(a, a + y);
cout << *pmax << endl;
```

Сумма

```
int sum = std::accumulate(a, a + y, 0);
cout << sum << endl;
```

Однако в данном случае мы имеем дело с учебным заданием. В учебных заданиях могут не разрешать пользоваться готовыми решениями из `<algorithm>`, а вместо этого требовать "рукописных" реализаций...

Answer (score 3):

В вашей программе непонятно, что делает переменная `x`

```
int y, x = 0;
```

, и для чего используется предложение

```
cin >> x;
```

Чтобы получить минимальный и максимальный элемент последовательности, можно использовать стандартный алгоритм `std::minmax_element`.
Например,

```
#include <algorithm>

//..

auto minmax = std::minmax_element( a, a + y );

std::cout << "1.Minimum = " << minmax.first << std::endl;
std::cout << "2.Maximum = " << minmax.second << std::endl;
```

Но я уверен, что ваша задача - это написать соответствующий код самостоятельно, а не использовать алгоритмы. Нет большой пользы от алгоритмов, если вы не понимаете, как они работают и не можете написать эквивалентный код самостоятельно.

Поэтому данный код может выглядеть следующим образом

```
int min = a[0];
int max = a[0];

for ( int i = 1; i < y; i++ )
{
    if ( max < a[i] ) max = a[i];
    else if ( a[i] < min ) min = a[i];
}
std::cout << "1.Minimum = " << min << std::endl;
std::cout << "2.Maximum = " << max << std::endl;
```

Сумму элементов массива также просто написать, используя цикл.

Например,

```
long long int sum = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < y; i++ ) sum += a[i];
```

Обратите внимание, что в этом фрагменте кода

```
cin >> y;
int * a = new int[y];
```

вы должны проверять, что `y` - положительное число. Вместо объявления

```
int y;
```

лучше было бы использовать объявление

```
size_t n;
```

И не старайтесь писать русские слова латинскими буквами. это плохой стиль программирования.